# Sata II and USB2 for external hard drive disk?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I'm looking for a good external HDD solution. Currently, I have a ST9500423AS 2 1/2" using SATA II, and I am looking for a good external HDD enclosure that keeps a nice transfer speed through the SATA II technology.

Does the SATA II keep a nice transfer speed through the USB2?

Comment: SATA II - 3.0 Gbit/s. USB 2 - .48 Mbit/s. USB 2 is going to be your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you lose most of the advantages of using SATA in the first place. USB needs more attention from the CPU for transfers than SATA, so while the transfer speed is retained, the overall speed drops. See if eSATA is a possible option instead.

Comment: Do the eSATA/USB Combo are the same thing than a eSATA ? if yes it's great, i can handle it on my laptop.

Comment: You mean [one of these](http://www.newmodeus.com/pics/eSATA-USB/eSATA-USB_port.jpg)?

Comment: Yes, exactly this, i have a ASUS B33E-RO157X laptop

Comment: That port will work with an eSATA cable, so you can use an eSATA enclosure.